# Devtool Chrome autosave not working properly

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, livereload

I installed devtool autosave yesterday and it was working properly. Now the server is running properly and it is showing DevTools Autosave 1.0.0 is running on http://127.0.0.1:9104
in the terminal but the css is not being recorded. I am using ubuntu 12.04 with chromium version 20.0.1132.47. I am editing a local file (file:///media/263003BB3003914B/Dropbox/Dropbox/Code/Jquery/effets-and-structure/index.html). I guess the problem is with dev tools options. I have tried many different kind of file path combos but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you probably got this working already but for anyone else this may be helpful. I installed it and thought it wasn't working but it was actually because I was just testing it on a HTML file with inline styles. It can only edit external CSS files. Seems obvious, but its an easy mistake to make when quickly trying to test it using a random file from your machine.

Also if you are working on a localhost then you need to be very specific with your locations. Open the extension in Chrome and drag a new route to the server. You can copy the localhost location you need directly from the browser, you just need to navigate to the local site's homepage. Now paste that in to the match section.

Next make sure you are linking directly to the css file/s in the save to section. On Mac it would look something like this -
/Users/your-name/Sites/your-site/css/

Be sure to keep the fraction (forward) slashes at the start and end of the location. If it still isn't working then you need to check the file location it is looking for in the terminal and amend it.